# How do I redirect to a View instead of UseDeveloperExceptionPage on Specific Http Error Status

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core MVC environnement. I want to manage a login routine when server give 403 error.

I currently use this configuration in my Startup.cs file :

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error/500");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
```

But I would like something like :

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            if ( error === 403 )
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/MyCustomError");
            else
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error/500");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
```

How can I deal with it ?

I tried to make what Microsoft explained with app.UseExceptionHandler in both case. In this way, I want to do what I want and show error if error is not 403 and return login View if it is.
The problem with this solution is that the displayed error is not a nice detailed page for debugging like app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage render.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC (for the full, classic .NET framework - up to v4.8) - or are you using ASP.NET **Core** MVC on the cross-platform .NET Core framework? Your tags, title, and question aren't quite clear and consistent about that

Comment: @marc_s I'm working on .net Core MVC, I fixed tags and question

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 403 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/MyCustomError");
        }
    });
    
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error/500");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#usestatuscodepageswithreexecute).Here is a demo(I test with 404,you can also add other status code error page to Error folder in the demo):

Startup:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCode", "?code={0}");
```

StatusCodeController:

```
public class StatusCodeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index(string code)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {
                code = "Unknown.cshtml";
            }
            return View($"/Views/Shared/Error/{code}.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

Error folder:

[image]

404.cshtml:

```
<h1>404</h1>
```

result:
[image]

You can also try `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`.